# Firebase was not reconnecting after internet is back in esp 12E/ NodeMcu

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp8266, reconnect

I have this code to reconnect:

```
void loop() {  
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED || WiFi.status() != 3) {  
    wifiConnect();  
    Serial.println("Trying to reconnect to firebase");  
    delay(1000);  
    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);   
  }
```

But if internet disconnected and again reconnected, this case    `Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH)` is not connecting to firebase again?!

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: do you use some older version of Arduino esp8266 core package?

Comment: Everything is uptudate except ArduinoJson 5.13( latest is ArdiunoJason 6) because latest beta of this version was showing error "'staticjsonbuffer' was not declared in this scope". I think that reconnection problem was related to Firebase Api not because of older ArduinoJson

Comment: try to add `WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true)` to `setup()`

Comment: Not working...actualy Wifi is reconnecting but after that firebase was not comming online once lose intent

Answer (score 0):

Try to use`ESP.reset();`

Example:

```
if (Firebase.failed()) {
  Serial.print("setting number failed:");
  Serial.println(Firebase.error());           
  ESP.reset();      
  return;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, fix Firebase.cpp by philipnguyen8588, AND fix FirebaseArduino.cpp of firebasearduino libs and worked perfectly
**1) Change Firebase.cpp:**

```c
void FirebaseCall::analyzeError(char* method, int status, const std::string& path_with_auth) {
    if (status != 200) {
    error_ = FirebaseError(status,
                           std::string(method) + " " + path_with_auth +
                              ": " + http_->errorToString(status));
  }
}
```

To:

```c
void FirebaseCall::analyzeError(char* method, int status, const std::string& path_with_auth) {
    if (status != 200) {
    error_ = FirebaseError(status,
                           std::string(method) + " " + path_with_auth +
                              ": " + http_->errorToString(status));
  }
  else {
    error_ = FirebaseError();
  }
}
```

**2) Change FirebaseArduino.cpp:**

```c
int FirebaseArduino::getInt(const String& path) {
  getRequest(path);
  if (failed()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return FirebaseObject(req_.get()->response().c_str()).getInt();
}
```

To:

```c
int FirebaseArduino::getInt(const String& path) {
  getRequest(path);
  if (failed()) {
    return -1;
  }
  return FirebaseObject(req_.get()->response().c_str()).getInt();
}
```

You can change all get function to: **return -1** for your code